# Ruby On Rails - Is it possible to store the result of a Rake Task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

In my api, I'd like to run a rake task every 10 minutes(for instance at 8:00, 8:10..). This task can take up to 10 minutes to execute(Thus, the next task can start its execution before the first one ends).
Since this task executes a lot of time-consuming queries at the beginning, I thought about splitting my rake task to two:

1. The first will execute these time-consuming queries. I'll fire this task every 10 minutes(at 8:05, 8:15...).
2. I'd like to use the result of the queries executed at the first rake task in the second one(which will be fired at 8:10, 8:20).

I was wondering if there is way a to store the result of the first rake task and use it in the second one? Or, is there another way to do what I am planing to build?

FYI, I don't want to use database storage since writing/reading takes a lot of time.

Comment: Back ticks are for marking up inline code. Please don't use them to highlight arbitrary terms in your questions and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense on the face of it. If your second task is dependent on your first, and your first only prepares data for the second, you either **need** to store the data in the database, or (more sensibly) just make it one task. Whatever other non-database storage solutions you come up with aren't going to be any better than a database.

If you need it to be two tasks, then modularlize things. Use three tasks; the first two can be run independently, and the third will invoke the first and pass the result to the second.

Comment: I'll generally have 10k ActiveRecord objects. This will take huge time to store on a db.

Comment: Then don't store it in the database, and merge the rake tasks, as I said. You cannot have it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use database tables or memcache/redis for storing the results.

for example, create a table called `cached_results` (don't use this name, use a name which is closer to your business logic) and store the results with a timestamp. Or similarly you can use memcache/redis with some sort of ttl